# PHP Facebook login - suddenly not working

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am implementing a website and I implemented a facebook login(PHP).
Suddenly it is not working anymore. When I am trying to login with facebook, it redirects me
to facebook.com when I am logged in facebook. But when I am not logged in facebook the script is working fine.

Could anyone help me?
the url of the website is: http://beta.noteslib.com/

Comment: please post the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using the old authentication method. Start reading the [updated documents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) to implement the right method.

Basically you can provide two methods for your users:

1. [Client-side](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/) authentication with the JS SDK.
2. [Server-side](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) authentication with/or without the official [PHP-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/).